# Add appropriate header files to Qt programs so that I can use Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE

Tags: qt

I want to create a shared library to communicate with database. I want to use Pimple idea in my implementation, but I don't know  which header files must be added to program so that Qt can find `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` and some other macros.
Is it necessary to add some command to `.pro` file?

Comment: It's defined in qglobal.h, but you don't need to include that manually (at least, not if your project is using QMake.) But you do need to spell the word "private" correctly or you'll get a symbol not found error.

Comment: Thank you MrEricSir. The private spell is incorrect for me. :D